# Does this modem qualify as a fax modem?

Tags: modem, pci, fax

I found this old PCI modem in my stash. I was thinking about using it to set up a fax modem on my PC. The only question is, does this qualify as a fax modem?

[image: a]

In other words, what signifies a *fax* modem?

Will in fact any 56K (V.90/V.92) modem qualify as a fax modem?

The chip label reads:

```
CONEXANT
RS56-PCI
R6793-12
E49786.1
0029 PHILIPPINES
```

Some additional info off the PCI plate:

```
HP P/N: 5184-4701
DC: 4037 REV: A
REORDER P/N: 5184-4701
SERIAL NUMBER: AZT006458
```

[image: b]

I tried installing this on Windows 7. It didn't bark. Drivers were missing. I know it works under Windows 98 SE (the original system) and most likely will work under Windows XP. I did try exporting the Windows XP drivers for this device (inf, sys, etc.) and using them for a manual driver install under Windows 7. Unfortunately it didn't work. So I will have to use it on Windows XP at least, or use it on a Linux machine.

Hardware IDs:

```
PCI\VEN_127A&DEV_2014&SUBSYS_4055122D&REV_01
PCI\VEN_127A&DEV_2014&SUBSYS_4055122D
PCI\VEN_127A&DEV_2014&CC_078000
PCI\VEN_127A&DEV_2014&CC_0780
```

[image: c]
[image: d]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick [Google](https://www.google.com/) search reveals¹, this most probably identifies as

```
PCI vendor ID: 127A, PCI device ID: 2013 ; data/fax
PCI vendor ID: 127A, PCI device ID: 2014 ; data/fax/voice
PCI vendor ID: 127A, PCI device ID: 2015 ; data/fax/voice/speakerphone
```

and therefore should qualify as a fax modem.  The way I see it every modem should, but I'm not definitely sure about this.

¹ see [this link](http://xmodem.org/chipsets/conexant/conexant_rs56pci.html)

Comment: You were right! This one does support fax, its ID corresponds to the one in the middle of your list. I couldn't get it to work under Windows 7 though. But it looks like it might just work under Linux, according to the page you linked. If I can get the drivers that is. This is a [softmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmodem).